# Resizing android button programmatically respect to maximum width (or height)

Tags: android, button, resize, height, width

I want to resize buttons I added programmatically to my Android app (Java code). They where added to the layout with a default width and height (because of no content). I want them to resize to 1/9 of the screen size to fill the entire screen (9 buttons in a row to fill the screen width). I tried to get the screen width (or the parents container widt, cause it fits to screen width). But got only 0dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The buttons where added as children of LinearLaout (width and height match_parent) to tabMain (LinearLayout in ConstraintLayout)

The root ConstraintLayout size is full screen width, but the LinearLayout tabMain is only buttons 9x button width (cause of 9 buttons inserted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a horizontal linear layout with width match_parent and weightsum 9,

after dynamically adding the buttons inside this layout set their weight to 1 and width to 0dp. This should work.

//I have implemented this for you

Here is the java code :

```
Button[] buttons=new Button[9];
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);

        for (int i=0;i<=8;i++){

            buttons[i]=new Button(MainActivity.this);
            buttons[i].setText("Button "+(i+1));
            buttons[i].setLayoutParams (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
            ll.addView(buttons[i], new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));

        }
```

Here is the layout :

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Used template to inflate horizontal layout with android:weightSum="9" and android:layout_width="match_parent", also a template for button inflate with android:layout_weight="1". This diesn't work. Or how can I set theparams programmatically?

Comment: I have edited my answer in which I have written the code for you to implement.

Comment: Is it possible to also resize height like with?

Comment: @k1ngarthur tell me how you exactly want to implement this, I will help you with that.

Comment: That's the problem :D. I've got no idea. I have a constraint layout. in there a linear layout (matches parent in height and width). there I programmatically new 9 linear layouts with 9 buttons (like above). so i've got a 9x9 matrix of buttons. it resizes perfectly to parent width (which is screen width, but in best case this must not be). Height is still default. It is generating a solitaer map (not the card game).